# High voltage AC-AC or DC-DC buck conversion

Tags: power-supply, buck

I have a schematic for an amplifier which if supplied a lower voltage will still work as a low-wattage amplifier. In the original circuit this is achieved using a 3-tap transformer:

[image]

I would like to "emulate" that 15W/7W switch using some buck conversion circuit.

The high tap giving 238VAC and the lower 173VAC. I have a transformer which gives me 238VAC, and I want to optionally "regulate" that voltage into 173VAC.

I tried searching for buck-converters but there seem to be none in this voltage category.
I thought about using a resistor network as efficiency is not a concern, but as the amplifier can't be treated as resistive that doesn't seem right.

How could I convert 238VAC to 173VAC or DC equivalent 314VDC to 229VDC?

If possible I'd prefer a cheap and simple solution over an efficient one.

Comment: What about autotransformer?

Comment: @MarkoBursic Seems very pricey to me, and also I can't find an appropriately rated one in my region.

Comment: It might be interesting to see what's behind that bridge rectifier. (as there might be a better solution) Also normal VAC ratings are given in such a way, that the same VDC will have the same effect (RMS (root mean square) or effective voltage).

Comment: @Arsenal updated image, should clarify my VDC needs are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal buck converters work with DC.  Since the transformer just feeds a bridge rectifier all you need to do is to do the variable buck conversion after the rectifier.

If efficiency is not a concern why not just leave it in the 15W setting?

What is the purpose of doing this change?  What will it do that it doesn't do now?

This circuit I found looks like it could be adapted to your needs.  This is a linear DC voltage regulator.  It should be incorporated after C25. It will need a low voltage supply as well to power the opamp. As designed it could go up to ~600V. If you change the value of R7 you can alter the voltage range (470K total would do about 300V). R2 could be reduced to a single 470K as well.  M1 should be put on a heatsink appropriate to dissipate 10-15W.

[image: High voltage adjustable power supply]

[Bartola Valves](http://www.bartola.co.uk/valves/2012/10/13/new-ht-bench-supply/)

Comment: This is a guitar amplifier, so volume setting influences the tone. So if you want to practice and not blast your neighbors you switch to lower wattage. 15W from a tube amp is quite loud. Could you show me a buck converter which supports these high voltages?

Comment: It is more difficult to work at these higher voltages.  Since efficiency is not a concern you could use just  linear regulator. Take the DC output from the rectifier and regulate it to the required voltage.  You might need to drop a 100 volts or so @100mA - that's 10W.  That will be much easier than a switching regulator.

Comment: What are the DC voltages and currents feeding the amplifier under the two settings? I see you have edited the schematic and the voltages are 314V and 229V for the two settings.  What is the current?

Comment: 120mA as can be seen in the schematic. For both settings.

Comment: That 120mA is at the transformer rather than after the rectifier - also it looks like transformer rating, rather than a measured current flow.